# Why does Twitter Bootstrap look like it's encrypted in Windows explorer?

Tags: windows-7, encryption

I'm a little perplexed, I run Windows 7 Professional N 64-bit and just downloaded the precompiled Twitter Bootstrap library from their homepage.

On extracting, I was given a prompt to backup my encryption key, and the files look like this in Windows explorer:

[image: Screenshot showing extracted Twitter Bootstrap files, which have green filenames]

I don't use encryption on this machine, why does this happen?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this while downloading Bootstrap this morning and thought I might have picked up some malware...

According to this [github issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11396) it's because the zip file was created on a Mac.

[This blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asklar/archive/2012/05/03/why-do-zip-files-from-mac-os-show-up-as-green-encrypted.aspx) describes the issue:

> It’s kind of funny really. The ZIP specification mandates that a
> program/OS creating a zip archive include a tag informing about itself
> to the program trying to decompress the archive. This information is
> called “version made by”, and looks like this:
>
> ```
>       0 - MS-DOS and OS/2 (FAT / VFAT / FAT32 file systems)
>       1 - Amiga                     2 - OpenVMS
>       3 - UNIX                      4 - VM/CMS
>       5 - Atari ST                  6 - OS/2 H.P.F.S.
>       7 - Macintosh                 8 - Z-System
>       9 - CP/M                     10 - Windows NTFS
>      11 - MVS (OS/390 - Z/OS)      12 - VSE
>      13 - Acorn Risc               14 - VFAT
>      15 - alternate MVS            16 - BeOS
>      17 - Tandem                   18 - OS/400
>      19 - OS/X (Darwin)            20 thru 255 - unused
> ```
>
> Now, interestingly, it seems that Mac OS is tagging the zip archives
> it creates with the value 3 (UNIX). Ok, so far no problem, I guess.
>
> The problem happens when Windows gets confused about how to interpret
> file/folder attributes. In FAT/NTFS, these values are stored according
> to this definition of File Attribute Constants. You’ll see that
> FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ENCRYPTED has a value of 0x4000.
>
> The interesting part is how Mac OS is storing its file attributes in
> the zip archive. Mac OS, being a UNIX based OS, uses the UNIX
> file/folder attributes system (and permissions, but that’s a topic for
> another time…).. Well, it just so happens that in POSIX, the flag to
> describe a directory/folder (S_IFDIR) coincidentally also has the
> value 0x4000. So it turns out the zip decompression code wasn’t aware
> that there might be other operating systems out there that might
> create zip archives…
>
> Can you change this behavior?
>
> No, but you can clear the encryption flag from the extracted files/folders easily.